# Corrupt bookmark: Cannot edit or delete

Tags: firefox

In Firefox, I have a bookmark I cannot delete or edit.

The bookmark becoming this way is totally my fault: I attempted to install a javascript bookmarklet but managed to save it with "http://" in front of the javascript. Bookmarklets should only start with "javascript:".

Now, the bookmark is forever locked and unusable, with the beginning of the URL like so: "`http://javascript:`", essentially two protocols being used. Firefox doesn't know how to handle it, so the bookmark edit dialog only half-renders with just Save and Cancel buttons, no other details. Right-click actions on the bookmark do nothing. The only interaction I can do with the bookmark is drag it to another position in my bookmarks bar.

I suspect I need to manually edit my bookmarks to either delete it or make the URL correct.

Perhaps one way of doing this is opening the bookmarks file (place.sqlite) with a database editor.

Any other recommendations?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVED:

Using [SQLite Browser](http://sqlitebrowser.org/), I was able to find the bad bookmark and fix it's URL. On the first try, the URL ended up being "#javascript:" when I re-checked it inside Firefox. Not sure how that # character got there, but I did a 2nd try and this time got a clean "javascript:" URL and the bookmark operates normally: I can edit or delete it.

To anyone trying this, definitely make a copy of your places.sqlite before making changes. The table containing the bookmark URLs is "moz_places" and it the column is just "url".